# At what point should we introduce water (or other liquids) to our infant's diet?

Tags: infant, eating, solids

We've just started feeding our infant solids and there are **lots** of resources to figure what when and what to introduce but I haven't yet figured out when we should introduce water along with it. It seems like a waste to give him something that doesn't include calories or nutrients but he's also taking in a lot more solids at a time and the solids are a lot less liquidy than the breast milk he drinks most of the time.

Should I be giving him a glass of water now? How much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, it depends on the child. Like adults, some kids will happily drink more water than others.

What is important is that when they start solids it is important that they start to also drink water to avoid dehydration. As soon as my child began solids we started giving her water in a plastic sipping cup that had been boiled and returned to room temperature. We didn't worry too much about volume, but just ensured we offered it to her at meals and throughout the day.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when giving your child water or other liquids that you are still giving the child enough milk/formula.  Water is much easier and may comfort your child, but it takes a long time for the child to eat enough food and get enough nutrients from it, so I was very cautious about giving my child water/juice.

I would recommend speaking to your pediatrician.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a question for your pediatrician, since your child's weight gain and other factors affect this.

The common information seems to be that water can't substitute for breast milk/formula, and that even the solid foods your infant eats don't give them the complete nutritional set needed.

Our son loves drinking water, and we sometimes need to give him sone while eating solids to convince him to finish.  We also give him a small amount after he finishes, which even at this age (9 months) he seems to see as a reward.

We are also dealing with a tendency towards constipation, and a little water after a meal seems to help with that.